# Help identifying a Cannondale road bike

Tags: identify-this-bike, cannondale

I appreciate any help in identifying this bike.  It's a Cannondale Synapse with "CAAD" on the frame, 105 handlebar shifters and rear derailleur, and Tiagra front derailleurs.  2 sprockets in the front, 10 in the back.  The serial number is IM32955.  I've been looking around on sites like those below, but

- I can't find an exact visual match (but 2010-2011 is close),
- The serial number does not make sense (if N is 2002 and letters increment by year, then I is 2023, per https://www.sportsrec.com/552678-cannondale-quick-cx-vs-cannondale-bad-boy.html).

Can anyone help out?  Thanks VERY much!

Sites for images:

- the cannondale bike archive https://www.cannondale.com/en/bike-archive,
- bicycle blue book https://www.bicyclebluebook.com/value-guide/cannondale/Synapse/

[image: full bike]

Comment: How many sprockets? Assuming the drivetrain is original, 105 went from 9 to 10 speed around the right time for it to be helpful in working this out (and 11 speed a little later).  The cassette lockring may even have the more detailed groupset number on it.  That could be good, though the cassette has presumably been replaced by now

Comment: Added in the main text.  Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It matches the 2013 Cannondale Synapse 5 105 Women's from [bicyclebluebook](https://www.bicyclebluebook.com/value-guide/cannondale/Synapse/).

[image]

Comment: And the mystery is solved.  Thank you!